# importing a python module from another repo

Tags: python, git, repository, project, git-submodules

I have written a python module. It resides in a repo. Now to get the unit tests for the module to run, they can't be subfolder of that module. The suggested structure to fix this is:

```
ModuleRepo/
  MyModule/
    __init__.py
    some_utils.py
      import .some_helpers
    some_helpers.py
  Tests/
    some_utils_test.py
      import MyModule.some_utils
    some_helpers_test.py
      import MyModule.some_helpers
```

Now that works just fine. If I run the tests, they are able to import the module. The module is able to import its own files (eg: some_helpers) by pre-pending '.' to indicate the local folder.

The issue is that a different repo now wants to share this module and I don't know how to make it find the module.

eg:

```
ModuleRepo/
  MyModule/
    __init__.py
    ...
  Tests/
    ...
AnotherRepo/
  using_my_module.py
    import ??? <-- how to find MyModule?
```

**NOT WORKING ATTEMPT #1:** 
I tried initially to include the ModuleRepo under AnotherRepo using git's submodule functionality. However I dont actually want the *root* folder for ModuleRepo, I want the subfolder 'MyModule' only. It turns out git's submodule doesn't do that - one cant choose only a part of a repo to include.

**UNDESIRABLE SYMLINK:** While a symlink might work, its not something one can 'commit' to a repository and so is somewhat undesirable. Additionally I am developing both on Windows and Linux, so I need a solution which works on both.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION: Turn ModuleRepo root into a module too (adding an **init**.py). Then I could use git to make it a submodule of AnotherRepo. My import would be ugly but it would be: import my.module.some_utils instead of import mymodule.some_utils

Does anyone have any better solutions?

Comment: The best approach I can see is to create separated projects and use them as dependencies by creating PyPI packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several possibilities.

- Tweak the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)
  variable somewhere at the top level of your code to make the `ModuleRepo` directory listed there.

  The upside is that this approach works with any solution you can
  use to have these two repositories aside of one another — be it
  submodules or subtree merging.

  The downside is that you'd need to repeat this tweak also in the
  test unit(s) of the code in `using_my_module.py`.
- Use [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for
  development.

  A part of the setting up the development environment for the project
  would be installing of "MyModule" "the regular way".
- If the "MyModule" module is not in flux and/or you are okay with
  *manual* periodical incorporation of the developments happening
  in "MyModule" into your "main" code base, you can go with so-called "vendoring" by means of using `git subtree split` and
  `git subtree add` commands (or the so-called "subtree merging" instead
  of the latter).

  Basically, the `git subtree split` command allows you to
  extract out of the repo hosting "MyModule"
  a *synthetic* history graph containing only the commits which touch
  files under the specified prefix — "MyModule", in your case,
  and the `git subtree add` allows you to "subtree-merge" that subgraph
  at the specified prefix in another repository.

  - [`git subtree` command](http://git-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subtree.html),
    and [its manual page](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt).
  - [The "subtree" merge strategy](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html).

Comment: It may be that the sys.path tweak is the simplest (and it is a commit to the repo so that is nice too). That will be my backup plan if the subtree split/add doesnt pan out. Thank you